# Camera renders slowly when using websockets in CameraImage stream

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Flutter camera app renders very slowly when using websockets in image streams. How can I improve my app performance? what is the best way to overcome this? On emulator it works just fine but on real device there is lot of delay and stuttering. Can we use async for camera app? If yes, how can I use it with this code?

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
    import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:archive/archive.dart';

    List<CameraDescription> cameras;
    Future<void> main() async {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      runApp(App());
    }
    class App extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Title',
          theme: ThemeData(

            primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
          ),
          home: CameraApp(),
        );
      }
    }
    class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
    }
    class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
      CameraController controller;
      IOWebSocketChannel channel =   IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://192.168.0.6:8000/');
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        controller = CameraController(cameras[1], ResolutionPreset.low);
        controller.initialize().then((_) async{
          await controller.startImageStream((onAvailable) {            
             sd(onAvailable);
          });
          if (!mounted) {
            return;
          }
          setState(() {});
        });
      }
      @override
      void dispose() {
        controller?.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      @override
     void sd(onAvailable) {
        var framesY =  onAvailable.planes[0].bytes;
        List<int> gzipBytes =  new GZipEncoder().encode(framesY);
        String compressedString = base64Encode(gzipBytes);
        channel.sink.add(compressedString);
      }
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
          return Container();
        }
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Container(
            child: new AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: new CameraPreview(controller),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```